# Page 2 of list of figures is chapter 0 (scrbook)

Tags: table-of-contents, scrbook

In my tex project, the list of figures has two pages because I used 36 figures.

My document class is scrbook. On page 2, I have a heading "Chapter 0: List of figures" (see the picture below). I would like to remove this heading. Is it possible? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunaly there is no MWE in your question. Default header entry would be "Abbildungsverzeichnis" - without "Kapitel 0.":

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,headsepline]{scrbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{pgffor}% only for the example

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{A Chapter}
\foreach \i in {1,...,100}% loop to generate 100 LoF entries
  {\captionof{figure}{Example caption}}
\end{document}
```

If you want to use page style `plain` for page 2 etc. in the lists and the ToC add

```
\AfterTOCHead{\pagestyle{plain}}
\AfterStartingTOC{\thispagestyle{plain}}
```

to the preamble.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,headsepline]{scrbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{pgffor}% only for the example

\AfterTOCHead{\pagestyle{plain}}
\AfterStartingTOC{\thispagestyle{plain}}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{A Chapter}
\foreach \i in {1,...,100}% loop to generate 100 LoF entries
  {\captionof{figure}{Example caption}}
\end{document}
```